# checkWinner is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

If anyone can help me that would be great the information about the issue is below the code.

```
  player1 = ""
  player2 = ""
  turn = ""
  gameOver = True

  board = []

  winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
    ]


  
  @commands.command(aliases=['tictactoe', 'ttt'])
  async def tic_tac_toe(self, ctx: commands.Context, p1 : discord.Member, p2 :discord.Member):
    global player1
    global player2
    global turn
    global gameOver
    global count

    if gameOver:
      global board
      board =   [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
      turn = ""
      gameOver = False
      count = 0

      player1 = p1
      player2 = p2


      line = ""
      for x in range(len(board)):
        if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
          line += " " + board[x]
          await ctx.send(line)
          line = ""
        else:
          line += " " + board[x]

      num = random.randint(1, 2)
      if num == 1:
        turn = player1
        await ctx.send("It is <@" + str(player1.id) + ">'s turn")
      elif num == 2:
        turn = player2
        await ctx.send("It is <@" + str(player2.id) + ">'s turn")

    else:
      await ctx.send("A game is already in progress! Finish it before starting a new one.")


  @commands.command()
  async def place(self, ctx: commands.Context, pos: int):
    global turn
    global player1
    global player2
    global board
    global count
    global gameOver


    if not gameOver:
        mark = ""
        if turn == ctx.author:
            if turn == player1:
                mark = ":regional_indicator_x:"
            elif turn == player2:
                mark = ":o2:"
            if 0 < pos < 10 and board[pos - 1] == ":white_large_square:" :
                board[pos - 1] = mark
                count += 1

                # print the board
                line = ""
                for x in range(len(board)):
                    if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                        line += " " + board[x]
                        await ctx.send(line)
                        line = ""
                    else:
                        line += " " + board[x]
                        
                        
                        
                        checkWinner(winningConditions, mark)
                        print(count)
                        if gameOver == True:
                          await ctx.send(mark + " wins!")
                        elif count >= 9:
                          gameOver = True
                          await ctx.send("It's a tie!")
                          
                          
                        if turn == player1:
                          turn = player2
                        elif turn == player2:
                          turn = player1
                        else:
                          await ctx.send("Be sure to choose an integer between 1 and 9 (inclusive) and an unmarked tile.")
                else:
                  await ctx.send("It is not your turn.")
            else:
              await ctx.send("Please start a new game using the !tictactoe command.")

  def checkWinner(winningConditions, mark):
    global gameOver
    for condition in winningConditions:
        if board[condition[0]] == mark and board[condition[1]] == mark and board[condition[2]] == mark:
            gameOver = True

  @place.error
  async def place_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please enter a position you would like to mark.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please make sure to enter an integer.")

  @tic_tac_toe.error
  async def tictactoe_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please mention 2 players for this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please make sure to mention/ping players (ie. <@688534433879556134>).")
```

This is in a cog and for line 34 "checkWinner" is not defined
but I've tried a few things and I cant get it to work. Any ideas. This is a tictac toe game and Im putting it in a cog. The cog is in a class with the name help. This code is python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the function call is above the function itself, Python reads down the code and when it calls checkWinner, It has yet to see that function.

You can either move the function to the top of the page.

or the more elegant solution is to function most things you can and use this as the bottom of the page which calls to a function at the top of the page.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   # do something here, call a function etc
```

Comment: Could I get a code sample??

Comment: Rather than code examples as I do not have your full code. I think this is worth a read.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/

It's a very useful function in python.

Answer (score 0):

Python reads code top to bottom, so in order to use a function, you must define it vertically before it being used.
You need to define Check Winner before the usage.
Move `def checkWinner()` before the function in which it is being used

Comment: still not going to work because then it tell if the game is over or not so def check has to stay there is there another?